# WebStorm How run nodejs as root to execute shell commands?

Tags: node.js, sudo, webstorm

How Can I run a node.js application through WebStorm IDE with root privileges in order to let node.js run shell commands?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to run WebStorm itself with root, parent node process will inherit the privileges.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking time to answer :D. There is another way to do this? No matter if isn't the easiest ;)

Comment: Kind of wrapper shell script that will run original node script via `sudo` and modifying system sudoers so that it doesn't ask for password when running this script?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by CrazyCoder, it is possible to do this with a shell script. To elaborate, the script would look something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
sudo /path/to/node "$@"
```

Additionally one would want to run `sudo visudo` and add the following line:

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/node
```

Finally, one would want to `chmod +x` the script and then specify the path to the script as the path to node in WebStorm.

Answer (score 0):

[WS=WebStorm]

A little variant/addition if you want to debug it in WS as well:
(without running WS as root):

Gist: WS terminal window + debug port + remote debug config

1. I'm using nodemon, so still wanted to use that
2. Open terminal window (Inside WS: Tools->Open Terminal..)
3. In the terminal run `sudo nodemon --debug=40155 --nolazy server.js` (40155 is the debug port to connect to later, you could just run `node` instead of `nodemon`)
4. Create a remote debug configuration in WS as explained [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#d110618e555) and set the port to 40155
5. Select that debug configuration and hit the WS debug button
6. Set breakpoints and profit :)

It's then very easy to just go back to the WS terminal window and rerun the server.

Answer (score 0):

To add to krisp's answer: You probably also want passing environment variables from your WS configuration to work.

To do that add `-E` to `sudo` in the scipt like this

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -E node "$@"
```